# Java Server on multiple network interfaces

Tags: java, server, network-interface

I wrote a Java **server** application that listens to data coming from the clients and then writes to a database.
I run the application on a **linux Ubuntu 12.04** computer with two network cards. While I was connecting to the network with a single network interface enabled it works absolutely fine, but when I enable both network interfaces I can receive data only from clients connecting to eth0.

The code of my server is almost classical:

```
    String address = "0.0.0.0";
    serverSocket = new ServerSocket();
    serverSocket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(address,port));

    while (true) {
            Socket clientSocket = null;
            try {
                clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                System.out.println("\n----Connection accepted----");
                ConnectionHandler handler = new ConnectionHandler(clientSocket, mysql);
                Thread handlerThread = new Thread(handler);
                handlerThread.setPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY);
                handlerThread.start();
           catch(Exception exc){
                //catch statement
           }
     }
```

The problem is something weird because **the address "0.0.0.0" should create a socket listening on all the interfaces**.

Something can suggest me how to solve the problem?

EDIT:
Probably the problem is in the SO settings.

This is the content of my /etc/network/interfaces file:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

This is the result of the *sudo lshw -class network* command

```
~$ sudo lshw -class network
[sudo] password for administrator: 
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: I210 Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 03
       serial: 90:1b:0e:0b:11:22
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=igb driverversion=5.0.5-k duplex=full firmware=3.16, 0x800005ae ip=10.0.0.100 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:18 memory:f7a00000-f7a7ffff ioport:e000(size=32) memory:f7a80000-f7a83fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: I210 Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: eth1
       version: 03
       serial: 90:1b:0e:0b:0f:25
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=igb driverversion=5.0.5-k duplex=full firmware=3.16, 0x800005b0 ip=192.168.150.100 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:19 memory:f7900000-f797ffff ioport:d000(size=32) memory:f7980000-f7983fff
```

Comment: As far as I know, the call to `InetSocketAddress(hostname, port)` will not make a wildcard socket on Java 8. Try to use only `InetSocketAddress(port)`

Comment: Still not working, it is something weird, when I connect just one interface it works, when I connect both the interfaces it stop working and when I disconnect the eth0 it restart to work, it is like the application cannot manage both the interfaces

Comment: Normaly it accepts connections on any interface for the given port. So maybe there is another issue in your config/software.

Comment: I just tryed with the VPN connection of my computer and I have the same issue. Any idea about the problem? There should be a right path to follow for fix it

Comment: Is it possible that linux does't manage the multiple Network Interface?

Comment: Please post the content of your  `/etc/network/interfaces`. And please run the following command and post the output too: `sudo lshw -class network`

Comment: answere in the post update

Comment: How do you config eth0 and eth1? With Network Managers or Wicd? Normaly the best way to configure a system with multiple network interfaces is static, because you only able to have one gateway. [Multiple Nics](http://serverfault.com/questions/197564/multiple-nics-with-static-ip-address-default-gateway-problems). So first configure your network, then start your application.

Comment: I did'n use Network Manager or Wicd, I configured the address and the gateway statically but with two different gateway, do you think is the problem this one? Have I to set the interfaces with just one gateway?

Comment: Your system is only able to handle one "default" gateway. So if you have more than one gateway configured, how should your system know which route to take to an outbound network? Only if you do routing with distinct networks this will work like a charm. Or prioritize the metric on one interface. But removing one gateway and try again is the easiest way. BTW: Where do you configure your network static? Normaly on Ubuntu the static config will be done in `/etc/network/interfaces`

Comment: Tank you for the explanation!! :D
I will reconfigure the system as soon as possible and post here the new `/etc/network/interfaces` I don't know why the last one was empty

Comment: You are right, the connection is configured trough the Network Manager.

Comment: I recommend to configure it static in the `/etc/network/interfaces` file. So your Network works from boot on correct. After that you can try to connect clients to the destination IP of your configured server. The clients have to be in the same subnet for calling the server else you need routing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved using something similar to this solution for multiple interfaces with multiple gataways:
[NetworkManager: per device routing tables](http://lamarque-lvs.blogspot.it/2011/11/networkmanager-per-device-routing.html)

In particular I divided the network in two size assigning some address to the tunneling interface and the other to the ethernet interface.

The only thing to pay attention is that instead of **up** the VPN uses **vpn-up** for his state.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to specify null to mean any address:

```
serverSocket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(null,port));
```

or in alternative:

```
serverSocket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(port));
```

both should map to any address.